# Pass command line args to sql (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, psql, args

How can I pass command line args to sql files ran with `psql` (Postgres)?

i.e.

`psql mydatabase < mysqlfile.sql arg1 arg2 arg3...`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [variable interpolation feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION) in psql.

If you specify `-v variable1=value1` or `--set variable1=value1` parameter on command line, then `:variable1` in the sql file will be replaced with corresponding text value.

Note: use standard-SQL quoted strings if you need quotes, spaces and so on.

Example:

```
echo "SELECT :arg1 FROM :arg2 LIMIT 10;" > script.sql
psql mydatabase -v arg1=relname -v arg2=pg_class < script.sql  
psql mydatabase -v arg1="'some string' as label" -v arg2=pg_namespace < script.sql
```