# How to change script variable of postgis script in batch

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a script like this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE someName TEXT;
BEGIN
  someName := 'something';
  DELETE FROM schema.tablename1 WHERE someColumn= someName ;
  DELETE FROM schema.tablename2  WHERE someColumn= someName ;
  DELETE FROM schema.tablename3  WHERE someColumn= someName ;
END $$;
```

Its saved as `something.sql`.

Now I want to call this script in a batch with this code:
`[POSTGISPATH]\psql.exe -h [HOSENAME] -p [PORT] -U [USERNAME]  -d [DB] -f  [SCRIPTPATH]\something.sql`

And that works perfectly. But now I'd like this `someName := 'something'` to be something that I ca change in a batchfile.

```
SET SOMETHING= 'something'

[POSTGISPATH]\psql.exe -h [HOSENAME] -p [PORT] -U [USERNAME]  -d [DB] -f  [SCRIPTPATH]\something.sql
```

And I'd like to change my SQL-Script to something like this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE someName TEXT;
BEGIN
  someName := %SOMETHING%;
  DELETE FROM schema.tablename1 WHERE someColumn= someName ;
  DELETE FROM schema.tablename2  WHERE someColumn= someName ;
  DELETE FROM schema.tablename3  WHERE someColumn= someName ;
END $$;
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass command line args to sql (Postgres)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50103585/pass-command-line-args-to-sql-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered providing the column value as parameter in your batch file? For instance:

Data Sample

```
CREATE TABLE t (f text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('foo'),('bar');
CREATE TABLE t2 (f text);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES ('foo'),('bar');
```

Batch file

```
#!/bin/bash

psql -d db -h localhost -c "
DELETE FROM t WHERE f= '$1' ;
DELETE FROM t2 WHERE f= '$1' ;
"
```

Executing the file and deleting all `foo` records from the tables

```
$ ./test.sh foo
```

And the records are gone:

```
$ psql -d db -h localhost -c "SELECT * FROM t,t2"
  f  |  f  
-----+-----
 bar | bar
```